# I am trying to connect ESP8266 with firebase but getting these compilation errors,

Tags: firebase, arduino, compiler-errors, esp8266, arduino-ide

I used the firebase demo program from the examples to test the device but it wont compile.

```
Arduino: 1.8.15 Hourly Build 2021/05/31 10:33 (Windows 10), Board: "NodeMCU 1.0 (ESP-12E Module), 80 MHz, Flash, Disabled (new aborts on oom), Disabled, All SSL ciphers (most compatible), 32KB cache + 32KB IRAM (balanced), Use pgm_read macros for IRAM/PROGMEM, 4MB (FS:2MB OTA:~1019KB), 2, v2 Lower Memory, Disabled, None, Only Sketch, 115200"

C:\Users\HP\Documents\Arduino\libraries\firebase-arduino-master\src\FirebaseHttpClient_Esp8266.cpp: In member function 'virtual void FirebaseHttpClientEsp8266::begin(const string&)':

C:\Users\HP\Documents\Arduino\libraries\firebase-arduino-master\src\FirebaseHttpClient_Esp8266.cpp:47:50: error: no matching function for call to 'begin(const char*, const char [60])'

   47 |     http_.begin(url.c_str(), kFirebaseFingerprint);

      |                                                  ^

In file included from C:\Users\HP\Documents\Arduino\libraries\firebase-arduino-master\src\FirebaseHttpClient_Esp8266.cpp:9:

C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\3.0.1\libraries\ESP8266HTTPClient\src/ESP8266HTTPClient.h:166:10: note: candidate: 'bool HTTPClient::begin(String, uint16_t, String)' (near match)

  166 |     bool begin(String host, uint16_t port, String uri = "/")  __attribute__ ((error("obsolete API, use ::begin(WiFiClient, host, port, uri)")));

      |          ^~~~~

C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\3.0.1\libraries\ESP8266HTTPClient\src/ESP8266HTTPClient.h:166:10: note:   conversion of argument 2 would be ill-formed:

C:\Users\HP\Documents\Arduino\libraries\firebase-arduino-master\src\FirebaseHttpClient_Esp8266.cpp:47:30: error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'uint16_t' {aka 'short unsigned int'} [-fpermissive]

   47 |     http_.begin(url.c_str(), kFirebaseFingerprint);

      |                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

      |                              |

      |                              const char*

In file included from C:\Users\HP\Documents\Arduino\libraries\firebase-arduino-master\src\FirebaseHttpClient_Esp8266.cpp:9:

C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\3.0.1\libraries\ESP8266HTTPClient\src/ESP8266HTTPClient.h:167:10: note: candidate: 'bool HTTPClient::begin(String, const uint8_t*)' (near match)

  167 |     bool begin(String url, const uint8_t httpsFingerprint[20])  __attribute__ ((error("obsolete API, use ::begin(WiFiClientSecure, ...)")));

      |          ^~~~~

C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\3.0.1\libraries\ESP8266HTTPClient\src/ESP8266HTTPClient.h:167:10: note:   conversion of argument 2 would be ill-formed:

C:\Users\HP\Documents\Arduino\libraries\firebase-arduino-master\src\FirebaseHttpClient_Esp8266.cpp:47:30: error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'const uint8_t*' {aka 'const unsigned char*'} [-fpermissive]

   47 |     http_.begin(url.c_str(), kFirebaseFingerprint);

      |                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

      |                              |

      |                              const char*

C:\Users\HP\Documents\Arduino\libraries\firebase-arduino-master\src\FirebaseHttpClient_Esp8266.cpp: In member function 'virtual void FirebaseHttpClientEsp8266::begin(const string&, const string&)':

C:\Users\HP\Documents\Arduino\libraries\firebase-arduino-master\src\FirebaseHttpClient_Esp8266.cpp:51:60: error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'const uint8_t*' {aka 'const unsigned char*'} [-fpermissive]

   51 |     http_.begin(host.c_str(), kFirebasePort, path.c_str(), kFirebaseFingerprint);

      |                                                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

      |                                                            |

      |                                                            const char*

In file included from C:\Users\HP\Documents\Arduino\libraries\firebase-arduino-master\src\FirebaseHttpClient_Esp8266.cpp:9:

C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\3.0.1\libraries\ESP8266HTTPClient\src/ESP8266HTTPClient.h:168:70: note:   initializing argument 4 of 'bool HTTPClient::begin(String, uint16_t, String, const uint8_t*)'

  168 |     bool begin(String host, uint16_t port, String uri, const uint8_t httpsFingerprint[20])  __attribute__ ((error("obsolete API, use ::begin(WiFiClientSecure, ...)")));

      |                                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Multiple libraries were found for "ArduinoJson.h"

 Used: C:\Users\HP\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ArduinoJson

 Not used: C:\Users\HP\Documents\Arduino\libraries\arduino_40755

exit status 1

Error compiling for board NodeMCU 1.0 (ESP-12E Module).



This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

Comment: firebase-arduino library is not updated for the ESP8266HttpClient library changes in esp8266 Arduino 3.0.0. maybe use it with 2.7.4

Answer (score -1):

Error compiling for board NodeMCU 1.0 (ESP-12E Module)., first, verify the version of your board, I haven't used firebase but I got that error using other libraries, so I change to 0.9, and problem solved, maybe you could try it, otherwise share your code maybe your problem is a syntax error related with your route server.

Comment: why didn't you try it if you want to write an answer?

Comment: This a 2nd generation/V2 board and it worked with an LED blink program earlier. The program i got this error is from an example code from the ide to check the firebase connectivity. (example name - firebase_demo).